# LibGDX: How to change a single sprites color?

Tags: java, libgdx

I try change the **Color of an single sprite** in LibGDX(Java). For example I want to change the color of a .png that shows a blue sheet. Like this:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("blue_sheet.png");
sprite.setColor(Color.RED);
```

There is the method sprite.setColor(Color tint), but it does **nothing** :( If I use SpriteBatch.setColor(Color.RED) it will **work**, but logically will apply the color on all sprites, and I **don´t want** to archieve this.

Comment: Have you tried setting the batch color back to white when you're done with your first coloured sprite?

Answer (score 7):

Its just 3 lines of code :)

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("blue_sheet.png");

batch.setColor(Color.RED);
sprite.draw(batch);
batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 3):

This may solve your problem.

[Libgdx change color of Texture at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034352/libgdx-change-color-of-texture-at-runtime)

It looks at creating a pixmap that you draw based on the pixels of your image. Based on each pixel's color your draw the according color on the pixmap.